# How to get the load event for images in a piece of html content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, loading

I've different html contents and each has some images. If there are any images in html they are loaded when I display an html content in lightbox div.

My problem is that I want to perform some action when all the images in the div have been loaded for any html content. How can I do that in Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: It sounds like the images are loaded on a user action, not when the rest of the page loads, correct?

Comment: yes, images load on user action

Comment: So how do you know, logically speaking, when _all_ images have loaded?

Comment: When I display html content, the images in the content start loading. Actually, I want to calculate the height of the area after all the images are loaded. Currently, I calculate the area but images are still being loaded so I don't get correct results(height).

Comment: Show your current code that displays the HTML content and calculates the area, ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep a count of how many images have loaded, and then when they're all loaded run your layout code. Something like this:

```
var $div = $(...); // this should select the div containing the images in question
var $images = $div.find('img');
var count = 0;
$images.each(function() {
    $(this).load(function() {
         if (++count == $images.size()) {
             // your layout code goes here
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think that there is a chance that the onload has already fired for some images at this point? I believe that you would have to run this code before the images in question have been inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure what the question was asking. Reading it again, I think it's asking how to run some code after the lightbox appears and the image has been resized. Might need to hack in a change to lightbox.js to do that.